# summarize functions in js

Tags: javascript, function, summarize

I would like to summarize some JavaScript functions. For example:

```
document.getElementByClassName("lamp")[0]; == selector(".lamp")[0];
```

In this example I haven't problem, my problem is the following code:

```
selector(".lamp")[0].selector(".school")[1].style.color = "red";
```

when i run this code console says :

> Uncaught TypeError: selector(...)[0].selector is not a function(…)

and this is my selector function :

```
function selector(string){
  switch (string[0]) {
    case '#':
      string = string.replace('#','');
      return document.getElementById(string);
      break;
    case '.':
      string = string.replace('.','');
      return document.getElementsByClassName(string);
      break;
    case '<':
      string = string.replace('<','');
      return document.getElementsByTagName(string);
      break;
    case '?':
      string = string.replace('?','');
      return document.getElementsByName(string);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('i cant select it --by selector.js--');
  }
}
```

what do I do?

Comment: Why not use a selector library like [SizzleJS](https://sizzlejs.com/)?

Comment: your `selector` is already a built-in in browsers, it's called `querySelector`

Comment: Your function returns something like NodeList or Element, these classes have no "selector" method. That's why the chaining doesn't work. So you should return something that has a "selector" member. (You could use the prototype mechanism, but I wouldn't recommend that.)

Comment: Begin with something like this (for the id case):   case '#':
    string = string.replace('#','');
    return (function(elem) { return {selector: function(string) { /* do something with elem */ },
                                     dom: elem /* the original element */
                                    };
    })(document.getElementById(string));
    break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use prototype:

```js
function selector(string){
  switch (string[0]) {
    case '#':
      string = string.replace('#','');
      return document.getElementById(string);
      break;
    case '.':
      string = string.replace('.','');
      return document.getElementsByClassName(string);
      break;
    case '<':
      string = string.replace('<','');
      return document.getElementsByTagName(string);
      break;
    case '?':
      string = string.replace('?','');
      return document.getElementsByName(string);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('i cant select it --by selector.js--');
  }
}
Object.prototype.selector = function(){
  switch (string[0]) {
    case '#':
      string = string.replace('#','');
      return document.getElementById(string);
      break;
    case '.':
      string = string.replace('.','');
      return document.getElementsByClassName(string);
      break;
    case '<':
      string = string.replace('<','');
      return document.getElementsByTagName(string);
      break;
    case '?':
      string = string.replace('?','');
      return document.getElementsByName(string);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('i cant select it --by selector.js--');
  }
};
```

this code run correctly without any error